# Non-negative integral solutions of $X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4<n$

Tags: number-theory, inequality

The number of non-negative integral solutions of $X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4<n$ (where $n$ is a positive integer) is?

Comment: Is this the same as for the sum from i=1 to n of the partitions of n in to 4 parts?

Comment: I dont think so...

Comment: Please make me understood using more words

Comment: So, this isn't a partitions question? I'm confused...

Comment: @a little don: it is (with slight adjustment) a [compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28number_theory%29) question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It' the same as the number of integral non-negative solutions to $X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4+X_5=n-1$, where $X_5$ is the difference, which is $\binom{n-1+5-1}{5-1}=\binom{n+3}{4}$

Comment: To expand on this: Each solution of $X_1+\ldots+X_5=n-1$ with nonnegative $X_i$ can be encoded as a word consisting of $n-1$ ones and $4$ zeros used as separation marks. The total number of such words is equal to the number of ways to choose a four-element subset from $(n-1)+4$ cells.

Answer (score 3):

Start with $X_1 < n$ there are $n$ values $0,1,\cdots,n-1$ so call $S_1(n) = n$.

Now we can try $X_1 + X_2 < n$ there are a triangle of values so $S_2(n) = T(n)$.

The triangular numbers are the sum of the first $n$ numbers and in general we have $$S_k(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} S_{k-1}(i).$$

These are just the binomial coefficients.